# libgdx non continous rendering

Tags: java, libgdx

According to the documentation (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Continuous-&-non-continuous-rendering) it should be possible to restrict the render calls that are made. However the render method is still beeing called every time I move the mouse. I would like to know whether its possible to restrict the rendering to only be done if some `action` is happening (or on demand, by adding the necesarry requestRendering ).

In the example below I set continous rendering to false and also called `setActionsRequestRendering` on the stage to set it to false.

---

```java
public class TestApp extends ApplicationAdapter {

    private Stage stage;

    private Drawable createDrawable(Color color) {

        Pixmap labelColor = new Pixmap(100, 100, Pixmap.Format.RGB888);
        labelColor.setColor(color);
        labelColor.fill();

        return new TextureRegionDrawable(new Texture(labelColor));
    }

    @Override
    public void create() {      

        Gdx.graphics.setContinuousRendering(false);

        stage = new Stage();
        stage.setActionsRequestRendering(false);

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

        Drawable imageUp = createDrawable(Color.WHITE);
        Drawable imageOver = createDrawable(Color.RED);

        ImageButtonStyle style = new ImageButtonStyle();
        style.imageUp = imageUp;
        style.imageOver = imageOver;

        ImageButton button = new ImageButton(style);
        button.setSize(100, 100);
        button.setPosition(50, 50);

        stage.addActor(button);
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {

        System.out.println("render");

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1.f);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        stage.act();
        stage.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        stage.dispose();
    }

    public static void main (String[] arg) {

        LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();

        config.fullscreen = false;
        config.width = 200;
        config.height = 200;

        new LwjglApplication(new TestApp(), config);
    }
}
```

---

According to the docu:

> If continuous rendering is set to false, the render() method will be
>   called only when the following things happen.
>
> - An input event is triggered
> - Gdx.graphics.requestRendering() is called
> - Gdx.app.postRunnable() is called

I assume that moving the mouse counts as a input event.

---

I would like that the render method is only called if the button actually needs to change its render state (button up / button over). If thats not possible at least the rendering should not be called when the mouse position is not `hitting` the button.

Comment: `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);` should be in create() method not in render() method. `super.render()` is useless because `ApplicationAdapter.render()` does nothing

Comment: @Morchul: Thanks for the tip, I cleaned up the example according to your suggestions.

Comment: I think it's not possible what you want. Because without calling render() every time you move the Mouse you are not able to detect a hover

Comment: Yeah, it can't calculate when the arrow is over a button without getting the mouse position input events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to `@Morchul` suggestion, I'll give remembering the state a try.
Thanks to `@Tenfour04` for pointing out the double buffering.

I added a InputListener in the create method:
(changed is new global variable / default: true)
(count is another global variable / default: 0)

```java
button.addListener(new InputListener() {

    public void enter(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, Actor fromActor) {
        changed = true;
        count = 0;
    }

    public void exit(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, Actor toActor) {
        changed = true;
        count = 0;
    }
});
```

and changed the begining of the draw method

```java
stage.act();

if (changed == false) {
    return;
} else if (++count == 2) {
    changed = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's not possible what you want. Because without calling render() method every time when you move the Mouse you are not able to detect a hover.

What you can do is to exit render() method before you render stuff if you see that button is not hitting:

```
@Override
public void render() {
    stage.act();

    if(!button.isOver()){
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("Render");

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1.f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


    stage.draw();
}
```

Comment: Just using button.isOver() won't be enough. But what you are saying is, that I would need to remember all `changable` (affected by the mouse position) components and their state. If one of them changes (which works because of the stage.act() call, if I understand it correctly) then I redraw the stage. I had hoped there would be a build-in mechanism that allows me to do that ...

Comment: @second Yes you must remember all changable (affected by the mouse position) components and their state so if you have five Buttons you must check all of them and if one is hovering or hitting you redraw the stage. It's maybe not the best way but at the moment I can't see another way

Comment: Keep in mind this still uses the GPU for the frame. LibGDX is double buffered so if you draw nothing, it will be copying the contents of one frame buffer to the other. In most cases this will be a lot easier on the GPU than drawing a bunch of triangles, though.

Comment: I updated my question with an example to get a notification if the state of the button changes, however there still seems to be some ongoing redrawing of the display even if stage#draw is not called?

Comment: @Tenfour04 .. I added a `counter` to counter the double buffering. Looks a bit ugly, but works. I`ll leave the question open for a while, maybe somebody has a better idea.

Comment: @second I'm not sure what the counter will do. Buffer swapping is handled way upstream in the backend. By the time `render()` has been called on your game class, the buffer swap has already been initiated. Then when the next buffer swap occurs and OpenGL sees that `glClear` was never called, it will copy the contents of the back buffer into the front buffer whether you like it or not.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I thought you might have replied on my `first` edit of the question. The problem without the using the counter was, that the `old` version of the display is getting rendered. That does not seem to happen if I render the supposedly same display twice.

Comment: Ah ok. I guess Lwjgl works a bit differently than how they have double buffering set up for the Android backend.